# How can I display Local Notification (Plugin.LocalNotification) in MAUI for iPhone

Tags: ios, maui, localnotification

I am using MAUI and trying to display the local notification on iPhone, but it doesn't show notification neither it throws any error. However, the same code is working fine on Android. I have already added UseLocalNotification() in MauiProgram.cs

```cs
//Send Push Notication
var request = new NotificationRequest
{ 
    Image = new NotificationImage { ResourceName = "icon.png", FilePath = "/Assets/icon.png" },
    NotificationId = 1000,
    Title =  "Changed",
    Subtitle = "Tab to see..",
    Description = $"updated",
    BadgeNumber = 50, //42

    Schedule = new NotificationRequestSchedule
    {
        NotifyTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1),
        // NotifyRepeatInterval = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    }
};
await LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Show(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for local notification on iPhone. But you need permission to do this from the user. [Asking permission to use notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications)

```cs
using UserNotifications;

var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent
{
    Title = "Warning! ",
    Body = "This is an alert!",
    CategoryIdentifier = "WARNING_ALERT",
    Sound = UNNotificationSound.DefaultCriticalSound
};

var trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(5, false);

var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier("ALERT_REQUEST", content, trigger);

UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, (error) =>
{
    if (error != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: The link for asking permission leads to an Apple developer page with examples in Swift and Objective-C.  Have you any example in C# that you have run successfully in .Net MAUI?

Comment: Bill, yes I have it, I am not working at the moment but I will see if I can find time to help you during the week. Else I am back next week.

Comment: Found the technique and documented it at [Request Notifications Permission in a .Net MAUI App for IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77754226/2200072)